# Is there a way to run xcode memory graph automatically using command tools?

Tags: xcode, memory-graph-debugger

I want to automatically export memory graph file while running UITest to detect memory usage info of specified component. But cannot find any command tools to achieve. Is There a way to run xcode memory graph automatically using command tools?